# Concatenating script output in mail body and send it as one email?

Tags: bash, text-processing, grep, sendmail

I want to concatenate all the output that I receive from the script and send it via single email. 
This is what I've tried but it ended spamming my inbox. :)

```
for f in $(ls "/vz/root") ;do
        if [ -d "/vz/root/$f/var/lib/somesoftware" ]; then
                if [ -f "/vz/root/$f/etc/network/interfaces" ];then
                        echo "Some program exist" $(grep address  "/vz/root/$f/etc/network/interfaces")| mail -s "Subject" -r fakeemail@gmail.com
                fi
        fi
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change where your email's body is plucked from (and also, don't parse `ls`):

```
for f in /vz/root/*; do
    if [ -d "$f/var/lib/somesoftware" ]; then
        if [ -f "$f/etc/network/interfaces" ];then
            echo "Some program exist" $(grep address "$f/etc/network/interfaces")
        fi
    fi
done | mail -s "Subject" -r cleverperson@example.com
```

Comment: Hehe, It's late here and my brain started malfunctioning. :) Thanks man, I'll accept the answer in 5mins!

Comment: Happy to have been of service!